# File uploading in background using Alamofire

Tags: swift, network-programming, alamofire, uploading

My application perform background file uploading using Alamofire. Also it displays uploading progress. When I start uploading process everything is fine. Than I do the next:

- Press home button (application goes into background mode)
- Open application (application goes into foreground mode)
- Progress info doesn't updates anymore (this is my problem)

My first approach is using ***uploadProgress*** method, but it wasn't work. Than I use observer to track ***progress*** property, but result is strange (console):

```
uploadDidStart video2.mp4
File video2.mp4 progress: 0.0095
File video2.mp4 progress: 3.012073e-08
File video2.mp4 progress: 0.016532185
File video2.mp4 progress: 0.059219763
applicationDidEnterBackground called
applicationWillEnterForeground called
applicationDidEnterBackground called
File video2.mp4 progress: 0.18531501
File video2.mp4 progress: 0.18531501
File video2.mp4 progress: 0.18531501
applicationWillEnterForeground called
applicationDidEnterBackground called
File video2.mp4 progress: 0.34003314
File video2.mp4 progress: 0.34003314
```

Upload service source:

```
import UIKit
import Alamofire

protocol UploadServiceDelegate: AnyObject {

    func uploadDidStart(_ service: UploadService, fileName: String)
    func uploadDidUpdateProgress(_ service: UploadService, uploadingFraction: Float, fileName: String, for taskID: Int)
    func uploadDidFinish(_ service: UploadService, taskID: Int, fileName: String, with response: HTTPURLResponse?)
    func allUploadsDidFinish(_ service: UploadService)
    func uploadDidCancelled(_ service: UploadService, taskID: Int, fileName: String)
    func dataEncodingDidFail(_ service: UploadService, with error: Error)
}

final class UploadService {

    weak var delegate: UploadServiceDelegate?

    private let fileTaskManager: FileTaskManager
    private let hostURL: URL
    private var sessionDelegate = SessionDelegate()
    private var tasks: [Int: NSKeyValueObservation] = [:]

    // MARK: - Init

    init(hostURL: URL,
         fileTaskManager: FileTaskManager = FileTaskManager(),
         sessionID: String = UUID().uuidString) {
        self.hostURL = hostURL
        self.fileTaskManager = fileTaskManager
        backgroundSessionManager = UploadService.sessionManager(with: sessionID, sessionDelegate: sessionDelegate)
        self.backgroundSessionManager.backgroundCompletionHandler = { [weak self] in
            guard let self = self else {
                return
            }
            self.delegate?.allUploadsDidFinish(self)
        }
    }

    deinit {
        print("deinit called!")
        self.tasks.forEach {
            $0.value.invalidate()
        }
        self.tasks.removeAll()
    }

    let backgroundSessionManager: Alamofire.SessionManager

    private static func sessionManager(with sessionID: String, sessionDelegate: SessionDelegate) -> Alamofire.SessionManager {
        let configuration = URLSessionConfiguration.background(withIdentifier: sessionID)
        configuration.httpAdditionalHeaders = SessionManager.defaultHTTPHeaders
        configuration.isDiscretionary = false
        configuration.networkServiceType = .responsiveData
        let sessionManager = Alamofire.SessionManager(configuration: configuration, delegate: sessionDelegate)
        return sessionManager
    }

    // MARK: - Public

    func cancel(fileName: String) {
        guard let taskID = fileTaskManager.tasks().first(where: { $0.fileName == fileName })?.taskID else {
            return
        }
        backgroundSessionManager.session.getTasksWithCompletionHandler { _, tasks, _ in
            if let task = tasks.first(where: { $0.taskIdentifier == taskID }) {
                self.fileTaskManager.remove(taskID: taskID)
                task.cancel()
            }
        }
    }

    func uploadFile(mediaURL: URL, reportID: Int) {
        let parameters: [String: String] = [
            "media_resource[report_id]": "\(reportID)"
        ]
        let encodingCompletion: (SessionManager.MultipartFormDataEncodingResult) -> Void = { result in
            switch result {
            case .success(let uploadRequest, _, _):
                guard let task = uploadRequest.task,
                    let fileName = mediaURL.pathComponents.last else {
                        return
                }
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    self.delegate?.uploadDidStart(self, fileName: fileName)
                }
                self.fileTaskManager.set(task: FileTask(fileName: fileName, taskID: task.taskIdentifier))
                let keyValueObservation = task.observe(\URLSessionTask.progress.fractionCompleted, options: .new, changeHandler: { task, _ in
                    DispatchQueue.main.async {
                        self.delegate?.uploadDidUpdateProgress(self,
                                                               uploadingFraction: Float(task.progress.fractionCompleted),
                                                               fileName: fileName,
                                                               for: task.taskIdentifier)
                    }
                })
                self.tasks[task.taskIdentifier] = keyValueObservation
/*
                uploadRequest.uploadProgress { progress in
                    print("uploadProgress \(progress.fractionCompleted)")
                }
*/
                uploadRequest.response { response in
                    let taskID = task.taskIdentifier
                    if let observation = self.tasks[taskID] {
                        observation.invalidate()
                        self.tasks[taskID] = nil
                    }
                    if let error = response.error, (error as NSError).code == NSURLErrorCancelled {
                        DispatchQueue.main.async {
                            self.delegate?.uploadDidCancelled(self, taskID: taskID, fileName: fileName)
                        }
                    } else {
                        DispatchQueue.main.async {
                            self.delegate?.uploadDidFinish(self,
                                                           taskID: taskID,
                                                           fileName: fileName,
                                                           with: response.response)
                            if self.fileTaskManager.tasks().isEmpty {
                                self.delegate?.allUploadsDidFinish(self)
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            case .failure(let error):
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    self.delegate?.dataEncodingDidFail(self, with: error)
                }
            }
        }
        backgroundSessionManager.upload(multipartFormData: { multipartFormData in
            for (key, value) in parameters {
                guard let data = value.data(using: .utf8) else {
                    continue
                }
                multipartFormData.append(data, withName: key)
            }
            multipartFormData.append(mediaURL, withName: "media_resource[data]")
        }, to: hostURL, encodingCompletion: encodingCompletion)
    }
}
```

It is looks like progress value updates when app goes into background.
How can I get uploading progress new values after application returns from background?

Comment: try to switch on Background Modes in Target -> Capabilities -> Background Mode

Comment: What exactly background mode capability should I enable?

Comment: Background fetch I think, take a look for tutorial https://www.raywenderlich.com/5817-background-modes-tutorial-getting-started

Comment: I have tried, but that didn't solve problem